# Command to list only output files of gcc operation?

Tags: command-line, gcc, find, ls

I have a directory with many c programs and some other files.

After performing `gcc -o output_name filename.c` on c files i have respective output files in the same folder.

What terminal command and how should i use it to display only these output files.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were told in your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/621773/85695), `gcc -o output_name filename.c` produces `output_name` which has no extension. Why should it? You didn't tell it to. Next time, run the command giving the output file name an extension. Something like `.bin` or `.exe` or `.myexecutableprogram` or whatever. File name extensions are arbitrary in Linux.

Since you have now already done this, you might be able to use a few tricks to get what you want:

1. List all executable files in the current directory. Since `gcc` will automatically set its output file to be executable, if you don't have any other executables in that directory, this might be enough:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
   ```
2. Search through your `history` for `gcc` commands, extract the output name and list all matching files:

   ```
   ls $(history | grep -Po "gcc -o\s*\K.*?\s")
   ```

   Note that this assumes your output file names contain no spaces or newlines and that you've never used variables as file names (for example `for file in *c; do gcc -o $file.exe $file` or similar commands.)

Answer (score 1):

with ls command we have option like hide

```
--hide=PATTERN
          do not list implied entries matching shell  PATTERN  (overridden
          by -a or -A)
```

So it will hide all matched and show what not matched.

For example as in your case

```
ls --hide='*.c'
```

As you said your directory contains C Programs and its output files , the above command will exclude all .c files and show what else.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, but i was looking for a command to display only these output files.
Answer you sugested is not useful if there are other files in directory.

Comment: do they have any extensions or any name specific  ?

Comment: @srkcb89 Based on your superficial question his answer is completely correct. Concretises your question, if you want concrete answers.

Comment: @Raja maybe with `find` and `-executable`

Comment: @A.B sorry for the confusion in my question.
 i edited it now,  can you please provide me an answer.
thank you