# What is the extension of output files of gcc operation?

Tags: gcc

If I do `gcc filename.c`, I get `a.out`

After performing `gcc -o output_name filename.c` we get the executable file `output_name`.

What is the extension of this file?

Answer (score 8):

Unlike windows, Linux does not depend upon extension of a file to determine what type of file it is. Instead, it will check first few bytes of the file and determine what type of  file it is.

Hence the output file given by `gcc` requires **no extension**. You may add whatever extension you want(by changing `-o output_name` to say `-o output_name.abcd`), but it is not going to mke any difference.

You can have a look at the output of the command

```
file ./filename
```

for example

```
:~$ file output_file 
output_file: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=9bc9fabf05a3d2e58c7780c48cd873cb2955b2ec, not stripped
:~$
```

Answer (score 4):

It does not have one. You can do `gcc -o myprog.exe filename.c` and it  will be called `myprog.exe`. Unlike Windows there is no default extension for executable files on Linux. If you want to mark a file as executable do `chmod +x file`.

`ls -l` shows you if the `x` (executable) flag is set for your file:

```
user@host# ls -l filename
-rwxr-x--x 1 ubu users 42 Mai 10 08:16 filename

- means its a file (d would be directory,see below)
r means readable
w means writeable
x means executable
```

The first triple is for the owner (`ubu` in this case),
the second triple is for the owning group (users) and the
last triple is for everyone else.

For directories the `x` means "can enter directory", so if `x` is not set you cannot do `cd directory`.

On Linux File Extensions are not special, the are just part of the files name.

Comment: I don't think `ls` has anything to do with this. It just shows file permissions.

Comment: chmod sets the file mode aka file permissions.ls -l shows them. I just wanted to explain that on unix and linux executables do not need to have special file extensions, but are made executable by the x flag.